# After javascript submits form in rails 6 the update action in controller not launching update.js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-6

Not sure if I am asking this question wrong, but I can't seem to find exactly the issue I am faced with.

I have a very basic rails 6 app for a task list.  Tasks are either complete or incomplete and the change/update of this is to be done via javascript (the html side works just fine).

Here is my form partial _task.html.erb:

```
<%= form_with model: task, html: { class: "edit_task", id: "edit_task_#{task.id}" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :complete %>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  <%= f.label :complete, task.name %>
  <%= link_to "(remove)", task, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the javascript to submit the form, tasks.js

```
function submit_update(){
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.edit_task input[type=checkbox]');
    const submitbutton = document.querySelectorAll('.edit_task input[type=submit]');

    submitbutton.forEach(button => button.remove());

    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        checkbox.addEventListener('click', () => checkbox.parentElement.submit());
    });
}

window.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', event => {
    submit_update();
    document.addEventListener('task_added', event => submit_update());
});
```

This part works just fine, but once submitted and based on this section of the controller

```
  def update
    @task.update!(task_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Task successfully updated' }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

My understanding is together this should launch update.js.erb, which currently looks like

```
unction update_task() {
  const current_task = document.querySelector('#edit_task_<%= @task.id %>');
  const complete_tasks = document.querySelector('#complete_tasks');
  const incomplete_tasks = document.querySelector('#incomplete_tasks');

  <% if @task.complete? %>
    complete_tasks.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',current_task.innerHTML);
  <% else %>
    incomplete_tasks.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',current_task.innerHTML);
  <% end %>
}

update_task();
```

I have tried changing the above to a single line using an alert call and it still never gets called.

If someone could let me know why update.js.erb is not being called, it would be much appreciated :)

If any additional information is required, please let me know?

**EDIT:**

On further testing, I have found that if I submit the update via the click of the button, ie remove the submission via javascript, that the update.js.erb is actioned correctly.

So it would seem the focus needs to be on the tasks.js file and how that submits?
What is weird is that when that is included, after the submit the HTML format runs just fine, just not the js format??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a number of days of trying to get the correct search words I have found the solution and happy to submit for others to find :)

The magic can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546#issuecomment-313572043)

The change for my example is as follows --

```
    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        checkbox.addEventListener('click', () => checkbox.parentElement.submit());
    });

// becomes

    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        checkbox.addEventListener('click', event => {
            checkbox.parentElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {bubbles: true}));
        });
    });
```

I have since edited the update.js.erb (does the same thing just a bit cleaner), but it also
needed an additional entry for newly added items to trigger having the entry change positions:

```
$ cat app/views/tasks/update.js.erb 
function update_task() {
  const current_task = document.querySelector('#edit_task_<%= @task.id %>');
  const to_task = document.querySelector('#<%= @task.complete? ? "complete_tasks" : "incomplete_tasks" %>');

  // Remove from previous list
  current_task.remove();

  // Append to the end of new list
  to_task.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<%= j render(@task) %>');

  // Advise tasks.js that new entry needs listener added
  to_task.dispatchEvent(new Event('task_added', { bubbles: true }));
}

update_task();
```

Hope others find this useful :)